# jQueryUI draggable and resizable issue in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue getting the resizable functionality working in the below jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/

For some reason, each time I try to resize, the element disappears and the below div is pulled up. Has anyone encountered this issue or any ideas on what is causing it to behave this way?

```
<div style="width: 99%; overflow: auto;position:absolute;">

        <div class="TimelineContainer">
            <div class="Task">
                <div id="coords"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="Event">
            </div>
            <div class="Resource">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the overflow? try setting it to overflow-y: auto instead

Comment: Well, I though I had an answer by giving the div a height. But it only works as expected if I resize the red box before the blue box. http://jsfiddle.net/WeXtJ/ Not an answer, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: @JasonP I've combined our suggestions, and they seem to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/17/)

basically the draggable script changes the position of the elements to absolute which sends everything for a loop.  If you account for this before hand though, like in my fiddle.  Its all good.

note:  I didn't change whatever you had going on with that yellow one, as thats probably separate from the issue you've asked about here.

change your css to this:

```
.TimelineContainer {
    position:relative;
    height:75px;
}
.Task
{
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: Yellow;
    cursor: move;
}
.Event
{
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: Blue;
    cursor: move;
    top:25px;
    display:block;

}
.Resource
{
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    min-height: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    background-color: Red;
    cursor: move;
    top:50px;

}
```

Comment: I've tested the fiddle you've created and tried to replicate my exact scenario on the following Fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/23/. I'm creating the bars dynamically and pushing them out onto the page in my actual example and i'm still having the same issue but there must be something else at play which i'll investigate - thankyou for your help

Comment: @user2616550 in your new fiddle it seems to be working for me.  Each block is staying in its proper row, at least in chrome.  Could you elaborate on what you're expecting to happen?